# How does the static allocation of a protoent struct work?

Tags: c, network-programming, free

In C, when I use the `getprotoent()`, `getprotobyname()` and `getprotobynumber()` functions from [`netdb.h`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getprotobyname.3.html), I get a pointer to a *"statically allocated `protoent` structure"*. So I understand there's no need to free any memory myself.

However, how exactly is that memory allocated? What is its scope? [The docs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.bpxbd00/getprot.htm) say that these functions *"all use the same static area to return the `protoent` structure"*, which *"is only valid until the next one of these functions is called on the same thread"*.

Therefore, at what time is that memory freed? That's what I'd really like to be able to fully understand. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory for these static areas is set aside at the time the program start and remains valid for the life of the program.

Consider this code:

```
char *getname(void)
{
    static char name[] = "my name";
    return name;
}
```

The `static` keyword when applied to a variable inside of a function means it lifetime is that of the full program.  This allows you to return a pointer to this variable from the function that is still valid when the function exits.  It's effectively a global variable whose name is only visible inside of the function.

The protoent family of functions do something similar.  They internally have a `static` variable that they populate and return a pointer to.

Comment: Actually, since the documentation indicates the structure is valid until one of the routines is called on the same thread, it must have thread storage duration, not static, or some additional memory management must be going on.